# Do I Need Receptacle or Crimp Terminal with Header?

Tags: pcb, connector, cables, header

I am considering to use Molex Nano-Fit Connector however i have never used it before. I will use it on a PCB Board and i am thinking to use only vertical header. I just desire to connect my cables to board. Is the Vertical Header enough or do i need Receptacle Housing or/and Crimp Terminal? For example when i connect the cables to my PCB circuit with [1053091104](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/1053091104_PCB_HEADERS.xml) vertical header, do i need also receptacle [1053071204](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/1053071204_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml) and/or Crimp Terminal [1053001100](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/1053001100_CRIMP_TERMINALS.xml)?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, you would need receptacle and crimp terminals, and it wouldn't hurt to get the proper crimp tool (which can be expensive).

Comment: While the officially correct crimp tool can be expensive, if you are only building a small number of units by hand, you can often get away with a generic one like these: https://www.pololu.com/product/1928. (I've seen similar ones for as little as $15, but I can't speak for the quality of those.)  You should be visually inspecting crimps, and pull testing some of them, anyway.